# 'Out of stack space' exception in for loop in vb6

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, vb6, adodb, vb6-migration

```
4           For i = 1 To mcolHistory.Count
5           gobjCommand.Command.Parameters("UID").Value = mcolHistory(i)
6           gobjCommand.Command.Execute
7           Next i
```

1. gobjCommand is a ADODB command object.
2. mcolHistory is collection of UIDs.
3. The stored procedure is already set in other block.
4. The function containing the 'for loop' is supposed to be called 300-350 times. Every time the function is called, the 'for loop' is also executed. The value of 'mcolHistory.Count' varies from 1 to 100 approximately.
5. Line numbers 5 and 6 are supposed to be called so many times. The stored procedure is run a lot of times.
6. Line number 5 throws the error 'Out of stack space' after a certain time, and the application crashes.

**Please let me know about what might be causing this error? And how to fix this?***

Comment: The `ADODB Command` object does not have a `Command` property (compare [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675022(v=vs.85).aspx)). So whatever `gobjCommand` is, it's not an `ADODB Command` object.

Comment: That being said, it's unlikely that setting a command parameter value is the thing that makes you run out of stack space. The assumption that ADODB causes the issue is most likely wrong. It's more likely that you have an error in your programming somewhere in the code that you do not show.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem will not be visible in the code above.

'Out of stack' really point to an endless loop of execution calling methods until the stack is full.

Check if mcolHistory.Count is too big and if not, check if you are recursively calling something.

Comment: Usually a for loop does not fill up the stack space, no matter how many iterations there are. Endless recursion seems to be the more likely reason.

Comment: I second your comment, really really unlikely (in theory possible) a for loop  size filling up the stack space, and recursion somewhere should be a part of it.